# Query, Display, and Filter Large Database Lists

Tags: mysql, ajax, jakarta-ee, collections

I am trying to determine the best method of collecting a large list from a database and then displaying and filtering the results on the client side. Let me give a quick example:

**Example:** I've got a database with customer data and currently it contains around 2000 records. This number is constantly increasing. On my website I have a page that I want to be able to query said database based on information such as name, email, phone number etc. and of course display the results (when a user types in Smith it returns all records containing the name Smith). I am planning on using AJAX so that I can query the database and display the results on the fly similar to how google does it. When a user begins searching, results will start showing up on the page as they are found.

**Possible Solutions:**
Unfortunately I am stumped on how to go about implementing something like this. I am considering using a ValueList pattern. When the user first loads the page, should I be querying the database and storing every record in a collection and then searching that collection list and displaying the results on my jsp page? Essentially creating a java database. The thing I like about the ValueList pattern is that I take one huge hit on page load and dump the entire database in objects stored in a list. What if the database is larger though, say 2,000,000 records?

Or should I be using a simple DOA pattern without the ValueList and query the database for each individual search? This would result in a LOT of database queries, especially considering that I plan on returning results as the user types in the search box.

**Edit:** The more I think about this, the more it is an AJAX question. My biggest concern should be how to query my database while the user is typing. Do I set some sort of listener to listen for the user to stop typing and then perform the query?

Comment: you are rather optimistic to extrapolate your current 2000 customers to 2000000. When you have so much customers the design of your application will hardy have something in common with what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) for this type of task.

Fields, which you are going to use for searching should be indexed with Solr.

Then you do an ajax query to Solr and get the result. You can set the order, number of items per page and show results only for current page.

Solr has a lot of other features that can be useful for you.

Comment: Solr is one option among many, but I accepted this answer because it makes the most sense to use a 3rd party option for me. Of course I could create my own version and reinvent the wheel, but thats counterproductive.